# Binary exponentation with modulo

Tags: python, reinventing-the-wheel, mathematics

I have implemented binary exponentiation. Is this good?

```py
def quad_pow(base, exponent, modul): 
    alpha = (bin(exponent).replace('0b', ''))[::-1]
    a = 1
    b = base

    for i in range(0, len(alpha)):
        if int(alpha[i]) == 1:
            a = (a * b) % modul
        b = (b*b) % modul
    return a
```

Comment: Are you trying to "reinvent-the-wheel"?  If not, the most efficient way is [`pow(base, exponent, modul)`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html?highlight=pow#pow) (Python 3.x)

Comment: No, I am not. I am aware that there are those functions, but programming doesn't mean that you use those default finished things. I was interested in how to programm this mathematical algorithm.

Comment: "Reinventing the wheel" is a perfectly sound practice; especially when trying to learn programming, or understanding algorithms.  We even have a tag for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One set of parenthesis are unneeded in this expression:

```
alpha = (bin(exponent).replace('0b', ''))[::-1]
```

You could write this as:

```
alpha = bin(exponent).replace('0b', '')[::-1]
```

---

Using `[::-1]` to reverse the string is nice, but using `replace('0b', '')` to remove the `"0b"` from the start first is unnecessary.  Using the `end` field of `[start:end:step]` would work ... you want to end just before the first character:

```
alpha = bin(exponent)[:1:-1]
```

---

Conversion from a string (`"0"` and `"1"`) to an integer (`0` and `1`) is unnecessary when you are just comparing the result to the integer `1`.  So instead of:

```
    if int(alpha[i]) == 1:
```

you could write:

```
    if alpha[i] == "1":
```

---

When you loop over a string, character by character (or any ordered container element by element), using:

```
for i in range(0, len(alpha)):
    if alpha[i] == "1":
        ...
    ...
```

is an anti-pattern in Python.  You should loop directly over the container:

```
for character in alpha:
    if character == "1":
        ...
    ...
```

If you need the element and the index, you should use `enumerate`:

```
for i, character in enumerate(alpha):
    ...
```

but that is not necessary here.

---

Updated code, with type hints and an example `"""docstring"""`:

```
def quad_pow(base: int, exponent: int, modul: int) -> int:
    """
    Efficiently compute (base ^ exponent) % modul

    Parameters:
        base: The value to raise to the exponent
        exponent: The exponent to raise the base to
        modul: The modulus to compute the resulting value in

    Returns:
        The base raised to the exponent, modulo the given modulus
    """

    alpha = bin(exponent)[:1:-1]
    a = 1
    b = base

    for character in alpha:
        if character == "1":
            a = (a * b) % modul
        b = (b * b) % modul

    return a
```

---

[PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) Note:

Binary operators should have a space on either side, so `(b*b)` should be written `(b * b)`.

---

See also [harold's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/240197/100620) for avoiding the conversion of the exponent to a string.

Answer (score 3):

The string manipulation is avoidable, by working with bits of the exponent directly:

```
def quad_pow(base, exponent, modul): 
    a = 1
    b = base

    while exponent:
        if exponent & 1:
            a = (a * b) % modul
        b = (b * b) % modul
        exponent >>= 1
    return a
```